# toilet won't flush due to ventilation problem

Tags: plumbing, water, repair, toilet, vent

I am new here and hope to get help.

Some years ago an amateur plumber installed a new toilet in my basement and he did not install a vent. The toilet did not flush, and I installed an air admittance valve, as illustrated in the following drawing.

[image]

I assume nobody did this, but it worked, until recently. I took away the aav, and it flushed very well. I bought a new aav, and put it there, but it did not flush.

I added another aav below the sink, which is just two feet away from the toilet, but it did not help. The aav won't help the toilet to flush.

[image]

I wonder what the problem or problems are. Why the old aav worked and now it stopped working? I took away the aav, old or new, it flushed perfectly. I also do not understand why the newly added aav does not help.

I would like to know how to solve the problem.

Comment: You probably now have a plugged drain.

Comment: If plugged, not totally, because water still flushes when the AAV port is open. I am thinking maybe the slope is not right, and thus the water is hard to go to the drain line

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember the manufacturer name, but I encountered one brand of AAV that had a seal that you had to remove prior to installation.  It was a soft plastic piece that kept the valve from moving around during shipping and prematurely wearing out.

Check your valve for such a seal. If you have the original packaging, it was noted there and on the instruction sheet inside the box.

Comment: The brand is Oatery and there is a plastic wrap that functions to prevent it from moving around, I guess. I peeled off the plastic before installation and I saw no other places that seal it. Thank you very much for your answer, but do you think what other causes may exist?

Comment: If it works with the AAV off and doesn't work with the AAV installed, you either installed it incorrectly or the AAV is defective. I can't think of anything else that would do it. If it doesn't work with the AAV removed, you have another drain problem you need to locate.

Comment: Can a new AAV be defective?

Comment: Everything can be defective. Most likely though, you missed something when installing.